# Percent decrease in value each month with SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to make a field in MS SQL that will serve as a target field, and I would like for it to decrease automatically each month. For instance, starting in April with a target 99.4%, May would decrease to 98.8 and June would be 98.3? Is there an easy way yo do this with SQL that I'm not aware of? I've gone through and manually entered them in with a CASE STATEMENT but I would like for them to not be hard coded.

Comment: What happens at the end of the year?

Comment: It keeps decreasing by the same percent until lets say 85%.

Comment: Why not creating a SQL job that will run an update on your field setting it to its own value - x% ?

Comment: There are historical records in the table, so the field would have to display a different target for each record depending on the date associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function/formula:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Sequence(@Date date)
RETURNS decimal(5,2) 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE 
    @InitYear int = 2019,
    @InitValue decimal (5,2) = 93.60,
    @Decrement decimal (5,2) = 0.20,
    @MinValue decimal (5,2) = 90.60,
    @Result decimal(5,2) = 0;

    SET @Result = (@IniTValue 
                  - ((DATEPART(year, @Date) - @InitYear) * 12 * @Decrement))
                  - ((DATEPART(month, @Date)-1) * @Decrement);

    IF (@Result < @MinValue)
        SET @Result = @MinValue;

    RETURN @Result;
END
```

```
SELECT dbo.Sequence ('20190101') AS '01/01/2019',
       dbo.Sequence ('20190201') AS '01/02/2019',
       dbo.Sequence ('20190301') AS '01/03/2019',
       dbo.Sequence ('20190401') AS '01/04/2019',
       dbo.Sequence ('20190501') AS '01/05/2019',
       dbo.Sequence ('20190601') AS '01/06/2019';

SELECT dbo.Sequence ('20200101') AS '01/01/2020',
       dbo.Sequence ('20200201') AS '01/02/2020',
       dbo.Sequence ('20200301') AS '01/03/2020',
       dbo.Sequence ('20200401') AS '01/04/2020',
       dbo.Sequence ('20200501') AS '01/05/2020',
       dbo.Sequence ('20200601') AS '01/06/2020';
```

> ```
> 01/01/2019 | 01/02/2019 | 01/03/2019 | 01/04/2019 | 01/05/2019 | 01/06/2019
> :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
> 93.60      | 93.40      | 93.20      | 93.00      | 92.80      | 92.60     
>
> 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | 01/03/2020 | 01/04/2020 | 01/05/2020 | 01/06/2020
> :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
> 91.20      | 91.00      | 90.80      | 90.60      | 90.60      | 90.60
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a860cf3ad2743a978810d0c4e40610a3)*

Comment: I can't upvote this solution but this is exactly what I'm looking. Thank you McNets.

Comment: My Repreputation points are to low, something about I need at least 15 point to 'up vote'? Seems silly to me. I did check it as the correct answer though.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad to help.